# C# regex for specific character or nothing

Tags: c#, regex

**Short version**:
How do I match a single, specific character or nothing within a longer, potentially repeating, pattern?

**Long version:**
I'm forming a regex to **count the occurrences of string 'word**' in strings which have the specific format of;
a hyphen followed by an integer number (any length) followed by a hyphen followed by the string 'word' followed by a hyphen, potentially repeating.
E.g.

> '-0-word-' (1 match)
>   '-10-word-' (1 match)
>   '-999-word-' (1 match)
>   '-1-word-1-word-' (2 matches)
>   '-1-word-1-word-222-word-' (3 matches) etc.

If the pattern repeats then I think the leading hyphen has to be optional as it is already the trailing hyphen for the previous match.

The best I have come up with so far is;

```
[-]?\d+-word-
```

which gives 3 matches for

> '-1-word-1-word-222-word-'

but it also gives 3 matches for

> '-1-word-1-word-X222-word-'

because the leading hyphen is optional and the 'X' is ignored. I want the leading hyphen to be only a hyphen or nothing. I want to make sure the whole string is rejected (no matches) if the format is not correct.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the above an exact input?

Comment: ' is not part of the match or string. Just habit when writing a string!Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of occurences and to check the string format at the same time, you can do this:

```
String input = "-1-word-1-word-222-word-";
String pattern = @"\A(-[0-9]+-word)+-\z";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Captures.Count);
}
```

When you repeat a capture group, each captures are stored, and you can access them with the `Captures` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
^-\d+-word(?:-\d+-word)*-$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/20

Comment: Thanks. That validates the string ok but only ever gives one match. I suppose I could use that first and then use [-]?\d+-word- to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regex demo for the word occurences.

Pattern is "-\d+-word(-\d+-word)*-"

http://regexr.com/3agkb

Comment: What is regexr down in future? Your answer will be useless in such a case. Put some explanation about your regex as well instead of just linking for a demo. [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Added the desc into the regex.